# How to implment messaging system based on Spring MVC

Tags: spring, message

I have Android devices and Spring MVC as server side. There is a button to send push message to get a device's current location by clicking. Device will send current location just after receiving the message from the server.
I would like to display the device's current location on the map when the location from the client will be delivered to server and stored into database. I think I need kind of messaging system between services and models. But I do not know how to implement it. I have heard of JMS but I never used it. I would like to get clear idea and some reference and examples how to handle my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I understand from your question that the event is fired by the user from mobile so no need for async implementation, but in case that you need it please check async functionality in spring 3.2 [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks helpful to me and I will have a look into.